# Image not showing in fixed div

Tags: html, css

For some reason the image isn't showing in the div I'm trying to create.
It's probably an easy fix that I'm just completely missing.

(just used a random image as example)

https://jsfiddle.net/57053L6h/

Snippet :

```css
.alert {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
   height: 75px;
   width: auto;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   padding-right: 50px;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
   display: table;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.alert p {
 color: white;
 display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}

.alert .icon {
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 /*animation: bounce 2s infinte;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <img class="icon" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/user-male-silhouette_318-55563.png" />
 <p>Lorem ipsum<br>
 I can only remember lorem ipsum lol</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to try setting the max width you actually want

```
   .alert .icon {
      max-width:100px;
   }
```

Comment: obviously remove the max-width and max-height you had.Here--->https://jsfiddle.net/57053L6h/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/57053L6h/6/ I'm adding a Bootstrap close feature but as you can see it doesn't get to the top right of the div. What is wrong with it? Placing it after the div also doesn't seem to work and I don't manually want to set the position with px.